# Why does parallelism cause lock escalation and where is the tipping point?

Tags: sql-server, parallelism, lock-escalation

I use the customized Stack Overflow database (180GB) and run a simple update query: (there is only a clustered index on the Users table)

```
Begin Tran
Update U set U.Reputation=100000 
from StackOverflow.dbo.Users as U 
where U.CreationDate = '2008-10-10 14:26:33.540'
```

[Query plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyYQc0ops):

[image]

This query causes lock escalation. I can't run a query using the same table in another window:

```
select * from StackOverflow.dbo.Users as U where U.id=11
```

If I add `option (maxdop 1)` at the end of the query to avoid parallelism, everything is fine ([plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyJXhRipj)).

Lock escalation does not occur in a smaller Stack Overflow DB (StackOverflow2013 - 52GB) ([plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1EysRoaj)).

How to identify what amount of data is causing the escalation?

I use SQL Server 2019. DB compatibility level is 150.

Table info:

- StackOverflow2013.dbo.Users -- 2 465 713 rows; 45 184 pages
- StackOverflow.dbo.Users -- 8 917 507 rows; 143 667 pages

Answer (score 5):

There is an element of chance involved.

I can reliably reproduce *lock escalation* in your scenario using the Stack Overflow 2013 sample database at `MAXDOP 8`. There is no lock escalation at `MAXDOP 12` (the most I can use on this instance) or at `MAXDOP 1`.

I rebuilt the Users table at `MAXDOP 1` using a `FILLFACTOR` of 100 before testing to ensure pages were as full as possible:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Users 
REBUILD 
WITH 
(
    FILLFACTOR = 100, 
    MAXDOP = 1, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON,
    DATA_COMPRESSION = NONE,
    ONLINE = OFF
);
```

Without locking granularity hints, the SQL Server storage engine chooses to process the Clustered Index scan using page-level locking. This is quite normal for a scan of a large table. Taking and releasing row locks would add too much overhead and a table lock would be bad for concurrency.

**Lock escalation does not occur in the serial plan** because SQL Server can release the lock on a page as soon as all the rows on that page have been tested against the predicate and found not to match. This is possible because the execution plan does not include any blocking operators.

The **parallel plan is different** because the *Gather Streams* operator is partly blocking. More than one row could be produced from the scan and held in the exchange buffers before rows from that packet are processed by the *Update* operator.

For correctness in the parallel plan, SQL Server must be able to hold locks on more than one page at a time if necessary. This necessitates the use of *lock classes*, which allow multiple locks to be held as long as the end of the statement, if needed.

The engine does contain optimizations to release locks held in lock classes early when safe, but the details are complex and undocumented. In your parallel execution plans the locks are held to the end of the statement.

More precisely, page-level update locks are taken at the scan operator. These are spread among the parallel threads and escalation is attempted by each thread independently based on the number of locks it is currently holding.

In my tests at `MAXDOP 8`, one or two threads end up escalating their page-level update locks to an exclusive table lock (table-level update locks do not exist). At `MAXDOP 12`, the work is usually spread evenly enough that no thread acquires enough locks to attempt lock escalation. At `MAXDOP 4` all four threads escalated their locks.

**Note:** one or more threads may escalate to a table lock while other threads in the same plan continue to hold locks on the same object at a different granularity because escalation was not triggered for those threads.

---

I don't have the 180GB Stack Overflow database and am not willing to download it just to test, but with more pages the chances of a thread acquiring enough page locks to attempt escalation obviously increase. At high enough DOP and with even distribution escalation might still be avoided. This is the element of chance I referred to earlier.

The script I used to monitor lock escalation 'attempts' and successes is shown below:

```
SELECT 
    IOS.row_lock_count, 
    IOS.page_lock_count, 
    IOS.index_lock_promotion_attempt_count, 
    IOS.index_lock_promotion_count
FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats
(
    DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', 'U'), NULL, NULL
) AS IOS;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE U 
    SET U.Reputation = 100000 
    FROM dbo.Users AS U
    WHERE 
        U.CreationDate = '2008-10-10 14:26:33.540'
    OPTION (MAXDOP 8, RECOMPILE);

    SELECT 
        IOS.row_lock_count, 
        IOS.page_lock_count, 
        IOS.index_lock_promotion_attempt_count, 
        IOS.index_lock_promotion_count
    FROM sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats
    (
        DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Users', 'U'), NULL, NULL
    ) AS IOS;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
```

Example output from a run where one of the parallel worker threads escalated:

[image: One thread escalated its locks]

I also used the `lock_escalation` extended event to confirm escalation:

[image: extended event output]

For more details on lock escalation internals, please see my series of articles:

- [The Lock Escalation Threshold – Part 1](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/09/sql-performance/lock-escalation-threshold-part-1) (threshold details)
- [The Lock Escalation Threshold – Part 2](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/sql-performance/lock-escalation-threshold-part-2) (parallelism)
- [The Lock Escalation Threshold – Part 3](https://sqlperformance.com/2022/10/sql-performance/lock-escalation-threshold-part-3) (lock classes)

There is also [Resolve blocking problems caused by lock escalation in SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/resolve-blocking-problems-caused-lock-escalation) by Microsoft, but that is imprecise in a number of areas, and incomplete in general.